# How to use "Count/per" in an sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

## Introduction

I have the following sql tables. Every entity has `one-to-many` variations and every variation has `one-to-many` entities.

```
- ENTITY (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, ID_ENTITY TEXT NOT NULL, wiki_title TEXT);
- VARIATIONS (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, NAME TEXT, LANGUAGE TEXT, TYPE TEXT);
- VAR_ENTITE (ID_ENTITE TEXT NOT NULL, ID_VAR INTEGER NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(ID_ENTITE, ID_VAR), FOREIGN KEY(ID_ENTITE) REFERENCES ENTITE(ID_ENTITE), FOREIGN KEY (ID_VAR) REFERENCES VARIATIONS(ID));
```

---

## question

How can I use `sql` language in order to count the number of variations per entity ?

---

## List of tables with sample data

## Entity

Table entity has 3 records

```
 ID   Id_ENTITE  wiki_title
48398|m.0nkkw65|Record label|
48399|m.0cp5rvm|Location|
117142|m.0n479hn|Yuika_Sugasawa|
```

---

## Var_ENTITE

Table Var_entite shows that Entities **m.0nkkw65** and **m.0760j5n** have only 1 variation whereas **m.0n479hn** has 2 variations.

```
  Id_entity Id_var
  m.0nkkw65|109628
  m.0760j5n|109631
  m.0n479hn|261081
  m.0n479hn|261082
```

---

## Variations

```
109628|A.G. Producciones|es|Label
109631|Screven County Middle School|en|Label
261081|Yuika Sugasawa|en|Label
261082|菅澤優衣香|ja|Label
```

---

## Results

As a result I should be able to see the following:

```
m.0nkkw65: 1
m.0760j5n: 1
m.0n479hn: 2
```

Comment: What queries have you already used?

Comment: I think it would help us if you showed sample data in each of the three tables.  This would eliminate a lot of guesswork.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I added sample data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a simple join, with a COUNT. Guessing at how your tables join together:-

```
SELECT a.id, a.id_entite, COUNT(c.id) AS variation_count
FROM entity a
LEFT OUTER JOIN var_entite b
ON a.id = b.id_entite
LEFT OUTER JOIN variations c
ON b.id_var = c.id
GROUP BY a.id, a.id_entite
```

Note that you might not need to join to the variations table (can just use the id from the var_entite table if there is nothing else you need from variations). Also if all items have at least one variation you could probably switch to using INNER JOINs rather than LEFT OUTER JOINs

Comment: I am running the sql command. I have a question why did you use "a.id" I didn't understand it in the query?

Comment: I just aliased the table names to avoid needing to specify the full name each time I referenced one of the columns on the table. So just lazyness!

Comment: no not that. I was just wondering why did you use a.id = b.id_entite.  Shouldn't it be a.id_entite = b.id_entite? i try it thank you @kickstart

Comment: bingo it worked. Yes i should just change **a.id** to **a.id_entite** that's all. Thank you so much

Comment: Ah, that. Sorry, was guessing a bit as to which columns had common values between your tables.

Answer (score 3):

This will work. Just count the number of variations associated with entity name like 'Angela Merkel'

`SELECT COUNT(v.ID) AS Number_OF_Variations
 FROM Variation v
  INNER JOIN VAR_ENTITE ve ON ve.ID_VAR =v.ID
  INNER JOIN ENTITY e ON e.ID=ve.ID_ENTITE
  WHERE e.wiki_title = 'Angela Merkel'`